# Can I connect my IBM Cloudant Database as the callback URL for my Twilio IBM STT add-on service?

Tags: twilio, ibm-cloud, cloudant, python-cloudant, ibm-voice-gateway

I have a Watson voice assistant instance connected using SIP trunk to a Twilio API. I want to enable to the IBM Speech-To-Text add-on from the Twilio Marketplace which will allow me to obtain full transcriptions of phone calls made to the Watson Assistant bot. I want to store these transcriptions in a Cloudant Database I have created in IBM Cloud. Can I use the endpoint of my Cloudant Database as the callback URL for my Twilio add-on so that when the add-on is activated, the transcription will be added as a document in my Cloudant Database?

It seems that I should be able to somehow call a trancsription service through IBM Cloud's STT service in IBM Cloud, but since my assistant is connected through Twilio, this add-on seems like an easier option. I am new to IBM Cloud and chat-bot development so any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, I don't believe that you can enable add-ons for voice services that are served through Twilio SIP trunking.

Unless I am mistaken and you are making a call through a SIP trunk to a Twilio number that is responding with TwiML. In this case, then you can add the STT add-on. I'm not sure it would be the best idea to set the webhook URL to your Cloudant DB URL as the webhook is not going to deliver the data in the format that Cloudant expects.

Instead I would build out an application that can provide an endpoint to receive the webhook, transform the data into something Cloudant will understand and then send it on to the DB.

Does that help at all?